# Solving differential equation $y''( \frac{1}{x} )+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{\rho}$

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

There is a my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591452/159409)  about solving differential equation,

I want to solve this equation by using *Mathematica*?
$$y''\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{\rho}$$

I tried:

```
DSolve[y''[1/x] + 1/x == 1/\[Rho], y[x], x]
```

but there is an error message

[image]

I also tried *Wolfram alpha* but there is no answer.

Comment: The error is telling you that you must write `y[x]` and not `y[1/x]`.  Do the appropriate variable change first.

Comment: Is `y''[1/x]` intended as `D[y[1/x], x, x]`?

Comment: if the parenthesis after _f''_ is intended to mean _f''(1/x)_ as in 'the second derivative of _f_ wrt the argument 1/x' then I don't think `DSolve[]` can handle the differential equation the way it is input. In this case, you should follow what Szaboics says. Otherwise, if the parentheses after _f''_ are simply meant as a way of grouping arguments together-in this case the single inverse term _1/x_- perhaps remaining after changing variables or other algebraic manipulations, you should precede the parentheses with a blank space (or remove them altogether) and append _y''_ with `[x]`.

Answer (score 5):

The equation can be solved by using `x` as an Argument for `y''` and not `1/x`.

```
DSolve[y''[x] + x == 1/ρ, y[x], x]

(*{{y[x] -> -x^3/6 + x^2/(2*ρ) + C[1] + x*C[2]}}*)

Function[x,-x^3/6 + x^2/(2*ρ) + C[1] + x*C[2]]''[1/x] + 1/x

(*1/ρ*)
```